# salesforce trailhead TOPIC: Display Records,Fields and Tables

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, compile-error, trailhead

I am new to salesforce platform, i am solving trailhead challenges i came across the error .solve this error

> error:`<apex:component>` is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1

REF:https://trailhead.salesforce.com/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_output_components

MYCODE:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock title="opportunities list">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="opportunities main">
            <apex:column  value ="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
            <apex:column  value ="{!Opportunity.Amount}"/>
            <apex:column  value ="{!Opportunity.Close Date}"/>
            <apex:column  value ="{!Opportunity.account.name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Did you create a `Visualforce Component` to try to store this markup? It belongs in a `Visualforce Page`, which is a different type of metadata.

Comment: no. larson but  I found this error Error: <apex:page> is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to reflect the actual error message you are seeing.

Comment: Larson:previously i created component but I removed it and then i proceeded further. suppose i created the component Tag and saved then i removed the component Tag and i added apex page tag because of this it showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailhead module is requesting you use apex:outputField components.

Code should look something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock title="opportunities list">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="opportunities main" >
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Name }"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Amount }"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.CloseDate }"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{! Opportunity.Account.Name }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```